# Exception handling for any mime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have a method in one of my `ApiController` which returns an exception if a variable is empty:

```
  passphrase = Appl::Config::Reader.get('passphrase')
  if (!passphrase)
    raise Exception.new "No passphrase configured"
  end
  passphrase
end
```

When the exception is raised, it is handled by this method in my ApplicationController:

```
def render_exception(exception)
    @errors = [exception].map{|e| e.message rescue e}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{
        flash.now[:error] = t('processing_error')
        render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/500.html", :status => 500, :layout => false
      }
      format.json {
        render :json => Error.new(@errors), :status => 500
      }
      format.xml{
        render :xml => Error.new(@errors), :status => 200
      }
      format.all{
        render :html => "#{Rails.root}/public/UnknownFormats.html"
      }
    end
  logger.error exception
  logger.error exception.backtrace.join("\n")
  end
```

The formats that I need to handle include things like PNG, JPG, GIF. It can pretty much be any format.

I have tried using `format.all` but I can't get it to work properly.
It's downloading a file instead of showing the UnknownFormats.html like I am intending to show.

Is there something I'm not doing right or that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just rescue from `ActionController::UnknownFormat`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 format.all{
    render :html => "#{Rails.root}/public/UnknownFormats.html"
  }
```

rendering :html expects an html string, not a path to a file. This should be `render file:`. I am not sure why it is downloading a file, are you sure your code reaches the all block?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have tried ```render file:``` now and it's still downloading a file, but it's downloading as a png file now, as that is the format that I'm currently trying to handle. Also, I am getting ```Rendered public/UnknownFormats.html (15.8ms)``` in the logs so I'm sure the code is reaching this block.